# Alternative to using string.Join in a LINQ query?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Any time I use the code below it throws the error:

> Method 'System.String
>   Join(System.String,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])'
>   has no supported translation to SQL.

```
        var items = from t in fc.table
                    where t.id== objId
                    select new
                    {
                        t.id,
                        t.name,
                        string.Join(...)
                    };
```

I tried using the LINQ Aggregate method but got a similar error.  Any suggestions on ways to get the string.Join functionality without the error?

Also, this code compiles fine.  It's when I try to do something with items that it throws the error.

Comment: I don't know much about databases but could you use a stored procedure that does the same thing as Join?

Comment: Most likely.  Don't confuse the join I am talking about here with a table join though.  For my situation i'd like to figure out how to do it using LINQ.

Comment: It's not possible to do everything through LINQ - only a subset of .NET functions are supported. `string.Join` is on the [list of unsupported methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force the query to run on the client first, to extract the raw data, then join the strings in memory:

```
    var items = from a in (from t in fc.table
                           where t.id== objId
                           select new
                           {
                               t.id,
                               t.name,
                               t.a, t.b, t.c
                           }).AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    a.id, 
                    a.name, 
                    string.Join(",", new[] { a.a, a.b. a.c })
                };
```